# Crawling a directory

Tags: c#

I have this test path:

```
private static string dCrawler = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "TestLetters";
```

Is there a way to say:

```
foreach (item in dCrawler)
{
     if (item.isFile)
     {
          // check file info date modified code
     } else
     {
          foreach (fileinfo file in ...
     }
}
```

so far I have only found ways to check a file in a directory.  Is the only way to do it by having two separate loops one for files and one for folders?

Comment: Check out [How to: Enumerate Directories and Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles();` that returns a `string[]` and use the string value to create your `FileInfo`. Like this

```
foreach (string n in Directory.GetFiles(dCrawler))
{
    FileInfo b = new FileInfo(n);
}
```

To get directories, you can similarly use `Directory.GetDirectories();`

```
foreach (string n in Directory.GetDirectories(dCrawler))
{
    DirectoryInfo b = new DirectoryInfo(n);
}
```

Comment: This would work for files only I assume?  I would have to create a similar foreach for DirectoryInfo?

Comment: Thanks, this got me on a good footing to do everything I needed to do with it. :)